# In thingsboards, How to save timeseries data in influxdb or Tdengine?

Tags: influxdb, thingsboard, tdengine

In thingsboard, I want to save timeseries data in influxdb or Tdengine.
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

As of 3.3.4.1 [Thingsboard supports](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/telemetry/) only Postgres, Cassandra and  Timescale databases. But you can use [REST rule node](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/external-nodes/#rest-api-call-node) to duplicate your data to InfluxDB via its [Cloud API](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/api/#tag/Write).

Comment: Use  REST rule node is a good way, But rest is not as powerful as JDBC connectivity